# How to specific a Java Generic class dynamicly

Tags: java, kafka-consumer-api, generic-programming

If I specific a method which return a generic class,how can I do than I can specific the type of generic class dynamicly ?
for example

```
  try {
        Class c =Class.forName(keytype);
        Class d= Class.forName(valuetype);
        KafkaConsumer<c,d> consumerconsumer = new KafkaConsumer<c,d>(PropertiesUtil.getPropsObj(configPath));
        return consumer ;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

But the code above is not OK. How can I do than I can achieve that?

Comment: You can't. Generics are a compile time feature. They literally don't exist (apart from a bridge method and a cast) at runtime because of type erasure.

Comment: Thank you dude,and I wander if there any alternatives

Comment: Yes.  Use raw types.  That's really the best you can do in any event.

Answer (score 2):

Generic syntax is good at compile-time only. None of the types in a generic class or method are available at runtime. This is called [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). So you cannot do what you want to do, at least not this way.

Depending on the original problem you are trying to solve, you may be able to use [wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) instead.

Comment: Thank you ,and I wander if there any alternatives

Comment: @SteveYN I already made a wild stab in the dark about one possible alternative. To give more accurate advice, we need more information about the real problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Do you mean the code like KafkaConsumer<?,?> consumerconsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(PropertiesUtil.getPropsObj(configPath)); ,and maybe it will work – Steve YN

Answer (score 2):

You can have your key and value class each implement a known interface.
Then you can assign or cast it.

```
KafkaConsumer<IKeyType,IValueType> consumerconsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(PropertiesUtil.getPropsObj(configPath));
```

or

```
KafkaConsumer<IKeyType,IValueType> consumerconsumer1 = (KafkaConsumer<IKeyType,IValueType>) new KafkaConsumer(PropertiesUtil.getPropsObj(configPath));
```

Read here about putting bounds on your generics.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: Be careful. `Foo<A>` is never a subclass of `Foo<B>` even if  `A implements B`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I will put a reference to bounded parameters that should help OP

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Foo<A> can be subclass of Foo<B> in certain circumstances, assuming you declare them as consumers or providers and do not break the contract.  This is one the features that got me hooked on Kotlin.

Comment: This question is tagged for Java, not Kotlin

Comment: I have combine your answer and the above one，it works quite well

Comment: @Code-Apprentice. im just saying that kotlin will magically allow what you say is prohibited.  anyway solution does not need cast.